# In SSRS, what is meant by the OR's "bitwise disjunction on two numeric values."

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'd like to have my parameterized menu allow one option to represent the numbers(i.e when you click on my menu drop-down option X it stands for all the numbers):

= 30 or 31 or 32 or 33 or 34 or 35 or 36 or 37 or 38 or 39 or 130 ( this is what I typed into SSRS by the way)

On SSRS it says that OR is for "Used to perform a logical disjunction on two Boolean expressions, or bitwise disjunction on two numeric values."

I've tried this:

```
=join(Parameters!ClientResponseRange.30 "," Parameters!@ClientResponseRange.35)
```

but it does not work

Comment: Does this help? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_OR

Comment: Also "disjunction" is just a fancy way of saying "either or" (in this context), so in a bit-wise "or" the result is 1 if either (or both) inputs is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the SQL `IN` function:

```
WHERE MyField IN (30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 130)
```

So if you have an `@Options` multi-value parameter, this will look like:

```
WHERE MyField IN @Options
```

Comment: OK I'm sorta understanding, but I'm a little blurry still... I'm struggling a bit to see how i'd adapt this to SSRS and what i'm doing. I'm also trying the temp-table ideae